# Django: passing context data between html file in different apps

Tags: python, html, django

How can I pass the context data (int his case profile_total variable) create in one of my views to the html template of another app?
This is my code:

**app1.views.py**

```
def view_profile(request):
    profile_total = UserProfile.objects.all().count()
    return render(request, 'profile/user_profile.html', {'profile_total': profile_total})
```

**app2.stats.html**

```
<div class="container">
<h1> Show </h1>
Profile submitted: {{ profile_total }}
</div>
```

Right now it's only displayed a blank space instead that the count of the profile submitted. Thank you all for your helps!

Comment: Your html is not `profile/user_profile.html`? (since you mention `app2.stats.html`).

Comment: Are you sure (a) that you render the correct template, and (b) that you trigger the correct view?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a *context processor*. This is a function that will run each time you render the template, we can use such context processor with:

```
# app_name/context_processors.py

def profile_total(request):
    from app_name.models import UserProfile
    return {'profile_total': UserProfile.objects.all().count}
```

We do *not* call the [**`.count()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count) here to postpone evaluating a query. That way we will only perform the database query if you *render* `profile_total` in the template.

Now we can register the context processor with;

```
# settings.py

# …

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # …,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # …,
                'app_name.context_processors.profile_total'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

and then we can use `profile_total` in all templates if we render it with `{{ profile_total }}`.